# std::async execution order guarantee

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, logging

I am trying to introduce logging to a multithreaded application. Currently, I am just using `std::cout` from the different threads. However, in that case, the order of the output is getting jumbled, even though one thread logged early, its output in `stdout` is coming after the log of another thread.

So, one solution can be to move all logging to an extra thread, but I don't want to manage one more thread. So I am thinking of using `std::async` to do the logging from the different threads. Is this possible? Are there any suggested ways to do this? Also is the order of execution of `std::async` guaranteed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

void print(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto a1 = std::async(std::launch::async, print, 1);
    auto a2 = std::async(std::launch::async, print, 2);
    auto a3 = std::async(std::launch::async, print, 3);
    
    a3.wait();
    a2.wait();
    a1.wait();
}
```

For the above code, is it guaranteed that the order of output will be

```
1
2
3
```

?

Comment: See [this repo](https://github.com/asmmo/parallelism/blob/fbcb17ad92e0851d23af0f9191ed78949a323c07/logger.cpp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of `std::async(std::launch::async, ...)` is that it's asynchronous (thus using not only "async" in the name, but repeating it in the first parameter).

You're not guaranteed much of anything about the relative order of things happening in threads created with `std::async`, unless you force synchronization using something like an `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable`, or some of the synchronizing primitives in `<atomic>`.

You say you don't want to manage one more thread, but then you create and manage not only one, but *three* more threads. I don't quite understand how this makes sense.

My own tendency would be to create a type to handle logging. Whether it uses a separate thread or not is its own internal affair. The threads doing the real work just do something like: `log(error) << "error 12345";` and it's up to the logging object to implement that efficiently. Yes, if you have a lot of other threads contending for use of the single logging object, it's likely to be best off running in a thread of its own--but they should neither know nor care one way or the other about that.

Answer (score 1):

> For the above code, is it guaranteed that the order of output will be
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```
>
> ?

No. [`wait()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait) waits until the value is available. It doesn't start the execution. It merely blocks until its done.

It may as well happen that **all of those `future`s** are ready **even before** you call any `wait()`s. In that case it's quite obvious that the order is not guaranteed (and completely unrelated to the order of those `wait()` calls).

Answer (score 1):

A way to offload logging from the current thread to elsewhere is to have a queue between the thread wanting to log and a thread actually writing the log to disk (or whatever). A queue is a good object to use, because it preserves order.

There's probably way better ways of doing this than what I'm about to describe (and I did this quite a while ago, so its bound to have been bettered). It's possible to adapt log4cpp so as to have a thread accepting logging requests submitted via std::queue. That's not a multithreaded thing, so what I've done before is to create a log event class, manage those using shared_ptrs, put the shared_ptrs to log event objects on the std::queue (so the posting to the queue is small, fast, and a minimum lock time on the necessary mutex). Then I've added in ZeroMQ with a PUSH/PULL pattern to allow multiple PUSHERs (posters onto the std::queue) to send 1 byte long messages to wake up a single PULL thread (that polls the zeroMQ and pulls from the std::queue). So logging consisted of the creation of a log event object, acquiring a mutex, pushing a shared_ptr to the log event object onto a std::queue, releasing the mutex and finally pushing a 1 byte message into a ZeroMQ socket.

Yes, it's a fairly horrific blend of std::queue and ZeroMQ, but it was quick to dispatch an arbitrary long log event without having to serialise the log event data in the thread send it.

A possible embelishment would be to turn off the mutex locking on the shared_ptr (it's not needed), or just use a raw pointer instead and try to remember to call delete.